# AuthorizationHeader no longer displaying in swagger document?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle

After I upgraded all NuGet packages to the latest versions, the swagger authorization header no longer displays in swagger open api document.

What happened?

ASP.NET Core 3.1

---

My code...(this use to work, but no longer works)

```
           startup.cs
           ......
        services.ConfigureSwaggerGen(options =>
        {
            options.OperationFilter<AuthorizationHeaderParameterOperationFilter>();
            options.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
            ....

        });
```

.

```
    public class AuthorizationHeaderParameterOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        var filterPipeline = context.ApiDescription.ActionDescriptor.FilterDescriptors;
        var isAuthorized = filterPipeline.Select(filterInfo => filterInfo.Filter).Any(filter => filter is AuthorizeFilter);
        var allowAnonymous = filterPipeline.Select(filterInfo => filterInfo.Filter).Any(filter => filter is IAllowAnonymousFilter);

        if (isAuthorized && !allowAnonymous)
        {
            if (operation.Parameters == null)
                operation.Parameters = new List<OpenApiParameter>();

            operation.Parameters.Add(new OpenApiParameter
            {
                Name = "Authorization",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Description = "access token",
                Required = true,
                Schema = new OpenApiSchema
                {
                    Type = "String",
                    Default = new OpenApiString("Bearer ")
                }
            });
        }

        if (allowAnonymous)
        {
            if (operation.Parameters == null)
                operation.Parameters = new List<OpenApiParameter>();

            operation.Parameters.Add(new OpenApiParameter
            {
                Name = "Authorization",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Description = "basic authentication",
                Required = true,
                Schema = new OpenApiSchema
                {
                    Type = "String",
                    Default = new OpenApiString("Basic ")
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Authorization header must be defined as a security scheme instead of a header parameter - see the ^^ linked Q&A.

Comment: do you mean in the AuthorizationHeaderParameterOperationFilter  class file?

Comment: The code needs to call `.AddSecurityDefinition(...)` and `.AddSecurityRequirement.(...)` instead of `operation.Parameters.Add(...)`. Where you put that probably depends on how your code is structured. The examples in [Swashbuckle documentation](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/#add-security-definitions-and-requirements) put those method calls inside `services.AddSwaggerGen(...)`.